# apache2 restart?

Tags: apache-http-server

Could you explain me why "`/etc/init.d/apache2 restart`" works and if I go to /etc/init.d and I just type "`apache2 restart`" it doesn't work ?

(It gives me help page instead of restarting)

thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Linux typing `apache2` will look in the system path and **not** in the current folder. You'll have to type `./apache2 restart`.

For apache there is usually the command `apache2ctl restart` which is in the system path. Or `service apache2 restart`.